# Defining OnClickListener separately or inside setOnClickListener()?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, getview

I was filling inside a `getView()` of an adapter while defining the click listeners, this got me wondering:

**Performance-wise**, is there a difference between these two implementations:

*Defining onClickListener separately:*

```
View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { //... }
};
mView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
```

and

*Defining onClickListener as the argument:*

```
mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { //... }
});
```

---

As `getView()` is frequently called, my though is that even small differences in its implementation would have big effect in app's performance. But I'm not sure.

So, which of the above is recommended regarding the performance/memory? Or aren't they that different to matter?

Comment: You are creating an OnClickListener in both your code snippets, so there is no performance benefit if you do it in getView(). You can have your adapter implement OnClickListener, then setOnClickListener to your adapter, that way no OnClickListener per view is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that actually depends on how many OnClickListeners do you have as anonymous classes.
it would be better to implement one click listener and set it to all of the views on which you want to get click event and sort the clicks out with view id's in OnClick(View v)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.some_view_id:
        doSomething();
        break;
   }

}
```

Comment: I have about 5 or 6  onClickListeners. So, it seems your solution would be better than both above cases. Also, I think passing the view's id instead of view would make it even more efficient.

Comment: Not really. I am not sure how will you pass the int id instead of View object since OnClickListener has only one method in which delivers View as a parameter. 5 or 6 click listeners is not too much of a load anyway but it is better to implement only one view and go through view id's to execute specific action.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My bad (I forgot it was override). A single onClick is also cleaner as my `getView()` is messy as it is!